# Probability Question involving coin tosses

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The question asks:

> Suppose a fair coin is tossed 3 times. Let A = the event that the
>   first toss is a head. Let B = the event that an even number (0 or 2)
>   heads is obtained. Show that these events are independent by showing
>   that  P(A|B) = P(A) and that P(B|A) = P(B).

Okay, I think I know how to solve this. The sample space for this would be:

*{HHH,HHT,THH,TTH,TTT,THT,HTT}*

Examining this, the probability of A would be 4/8 (or 1/2). This would also be the probability of B.

This means that the P(A|B) and P(B|A) would both be equal to 2/8 / 1/2, both of which comes out to one half, showing that P(A|B) = P(A) and P(B|A) = P(B).

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing $HTH$ from your sample space.

My main problem is here:

> This means that the P(A|B) and P(B|A) would both be equal to 2/8 / 1/2, both of which comes out to one half, showing that P(A|B) = P(A) and P(B|A) = P(B).

This is correct, but you haven't actually showed it. To formally prove it, you need to show which members of the set that satisfy $A$ satisfy $B$ and which members of the set that satisfy $B$ satisfy $A$. It's clear that you've done the work, but this conclusion doesn't immediately follow from what you've shown.

Comment: Ah, I see - so specify A intersection B. Thank you!